# Angular, Observables and Garbage Collection?

Tags: angular, garbage-collection, angular2-observables

Throughout the years, I have been aware of cleaning up after myself when it comes to event listeners.

What should I be doing in the Angular world when it comes to situations where you are not using `first()` or `takeX()` etc.  For example consider a form control which lasts forever.

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Lets assume that I am finished with my form now and want to move on.

Do I need to assign every observable like this to a `Subscription` property in the same way that I would require a reference with a `addEventListener` so I could later `removeEventListener`?

If there are situations where I do and don't need to care, is there is a good explanation of that anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unsubscribe when you're done. For example:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.something$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

You can take advantage of `async` pipe that does unsubscribing automatically.

```
<p>{{ something$ |async }}</p>
```

in this case you don't have to subscribe/unsubscribe manually.

**Garbage collection**

I did some testing a while ago (not sure if this is still relevant), but I noticed when `subscription()` is just an empty function, browser releases memory sooner. For example, if you look at the Chrome's task manager memory usage and don't unsubscribe:

```
this.something$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));    
this.something$.do(value => console.log(value)).subscribe();
```

memory usage will go down for 2nd case, and not for the 1st case. Not sure if this is feature/bug/other, nor why it is happening; just an observation (: